# How to query documents in mongodb (pymongo) where all keywords exist in a field?

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of keywords:

```
keywords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

For now I query for only 1 keyword like this:

```
collection.find({'documenttextfield': {'$regex': ' '+keyword+' '}})
```

I'm in no way a guru in regex so i do the reggae with spaces on the side of the keyword to find exact match.

But what i want now is, having that `keywords` list, to query the documents and find those which have each of the keywords from the list in the `documenttextfield`.

I have some ideas of how to do this, but they are all a bit too complex and I feel I'm missing something...

Comment: A single regular expression won't help you if you don't know the order in which the keywords appear. Did you consider using a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) with a [`$text` search](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/). It might be a far better solution than using regular expressions. However, text search returns documents based on a scoring-algorithm, so you might get some results which don't have all the keywords you are looking for.

If you can't or don't want to add a text index to this field, using a single regular expression would be quite a pain because you don't know the order in which these words appear. I don't claim it is impossible to write, but you will end up with a horrible abomination even for regex standards. It would be far easier to use the regex operator multiple time by using the `$and` operator.

Also, using a space as delimeter is going to fail when the word is at the beginning or end of the string or followed by a period or comma. Use the word-boundary token (`\b`) instead.

```
collection.find(
    { $and : [
              {'documenttextfield': {'$regex': '\b' +keyword1+'\b'}},
              {'documenttextfield': {'$regex': '\b' +keyword2+'\b'}},
              {'documenttextfield': {'$regex': '\b' +keyword3+'\b'}},
         ]
    });
```

Keep in mind that this is a really slow query, because it will run these three regular expressions on every single document of the collection. When this is a performance-critical query, seriously consider if a text index really won't do. Failing this, the last straw to grasp would be to extract any keywords from the `documenttextfield` field someone could search for (which might be every unique word in it) into a new array-field `documenttextfield_keywords`, create a normal index on that field, and search on that field with the [`$all` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) (no regular expression required in that case).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give a shot with assembling keywords per text field and storing on the same document! it's actually a very neat a nice way. I have the means to do that and I think that should work way better than 3 regexs for sure!

Comment: @GeekSince1982 Using `$all` is far less obtuse `{ "documenttextfield": { "$all":  [re.compile('\b'+keyword+'\b',re.IGNORECASE) for keyword in keywords] } }`. But unless you need "stopwords" like `"and"`, `"or"` to be included the `$text` is probably more efficient. Note that it does require a significantly larger index to achieve that efficiency, and is usually suited to "larger" text fields in a document than smaller ones.

Comment: @GeekSince1982 The "other" omission here is that a "text search" will not return **only** the documents that matched the list of terms. The documents with **all** matches will be the "top ranked" results, but other terms included will be returned since text search conditions are "OR" conditions. There is no way to write "AND" exclusively. Also my main point above is that the answer incorrectly presumes `$all` **requires** an array to function. It does not, and is actually of course a "list of arguments" that need to match the property, and not the other way around. People get this wrong a lot.

Comment: I tried searching with `$text` and sorting on `{score:{ $meta: "textScore"}}` . It works ok but the `textScore` is not very reliable or maybe i don't fully understand the scoring mechanism. Basically I see that results get high score if one keyword was mentioned many times or all keywords were found. While I need to get results with all keywords for sure.