# Query mongodb collection: $text with a score vs. $all (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, search, full-text-search

I have documents like this in a big collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("879878g9fds87gsd8978f"),
   text1: "this ball and this ball are toys in the house",
   text2: "this is a car and a space boat",
   text3: "this ball is a toys in the house this is a car and a space boat computer is a hammer",
   keywordst3: ["ball", "toys", "house", "car", "boat", "computer", "hammer"],
}
```

- keywordst3 - is a field which assembles and array of all words from text1, text2, text3.

I receive a user input (search criteria) and I need to find a relevant document from the collection.

And I'm facing a difficulty here when it comes to the search criteria which consists of 2+ words.

So using above document as an example:

**Search criteria: `ball`**

1-st way:

```
keywords = ['ball']
collection.find({"keywordst3": {'$all': 'keywords'})
```

This will match my search to the keywords list and return the document(s) correctly.

2-nd way:

```
keywords = 'ball'
collection.find({'$text': {'$search': keywords}}, {'score': {'$meta': "textScore"}})
```

This will return me a cursor of documents with the relevant "textScore". The higher the score the more relevant the document is to the search criteria. In the case of 1 word search, the score is higher if the word is found several times.

This scenario works ok. But now the challenge I have:

**Search criteria: `ball toys`**

1-st way:

```
keywords = ['ball', 'toys']
collection.find({"keywordst3": {'$all': 'keywords'})
```

Returns me the document(s) where BOTH KEYWORDS were found in the `keywordst3`. "Hard" AND condition.

2-nd way:

```
keywords = 'ball toys'
collection.find({'$text': {'$search': keywords}}, {'score': {'$meta': "textScore"}})
```

And things get funky here... I get a list of documents with scores, but I can't fully trust them:

- A score of 0.9 might be for a document with both words matched.
- A score of 1.1 might be for a document where ONE word was mentioned 4 times.
- A score of 0.6 might be for a document where one word matched once.
- ...and so on... i can't put a finger on the rule of scoring...

So now I'm puzzled on how to provide the best search results to my users.

My thoughts so far:

- On one hand, the `$all` match is a good thing and stably returns the exact match. But what if a users searches for two words relevant to each other. For example: `bernie sanders`. In my collection of documents (these are actually news articles), some documents will just have `bernie`... `$all` will skip those.
- That's where `$text` and `textScore` come in. If user searches for a phrase which has a relevance between two words: `bernie sanders` then `$text` and `textScore` is a very good way to give a good result, sorting by the `textscore`, even if only ONE word is mentioned in the document. HOWEVER if two (or more) words in the search phrase are not relevant to each other: `ball ship` - with the above example of the document the score will be still high for that document since `ball` is mentioned two times, but `ship` is not even there at all, so if I still base my result on the score - i might give a user not correct result.

One way I'm thinking on tackling this is to use BOTH approaches.

1. First use `$text` and get a set of documents (300...) sorted descending by their their scores. So the highest match is at the top.
2. Iterate through that set trying to match both keywords to the keywords list.

   - IF in the step 2 I find a document from a high score set with both keywords existing in the keywords list = Jackpot! it's definitely a good result.
   - IF in the step 2 I don't fine a document with both keywords then i just pick the document with the HIGHEST SCORE and give it to the user. It might still be incorrect, but at least "i did my best" and the highest score gives a good chance of a document being correct.

Would you please asses my "madness" and enlighten me if I'm missing something? What would be a better approach to this?

Comment: Typo in your question, or possibly a misunderstanding. It should be `collection.find({"keywordst3": {'$all': keywords }})`  where `keywords` is the array argument supplied to `$all`. You also got it wrong since unless `"keywordst3"` is an **array** of strings itself it would instead be `collecgtion.find({ "keywordst3": { "$all":[re.compile('\b'+keyword+'\b',re.IGNORECASE) for keyword in keywords] } })`. That's what I told you before. Without a regex the usage of `$all` requires "major surgery" on your structure to include an array of each different "word" in a phrase.

Comment: Again what was said on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36251768/5031275) is that `$text` and `$regex` searches are not the same thing. A "text" search **cannot** be an "AND" condition, but the `$all` actually **is**. A "text" search "should" score the document that matches **ALL** words at the top of results, but it will not return **ONLY** the results that match ALL words. The main factor will be your "text field" to match against. If it [exceeds 1024 bytes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) then you **must** use a "text" index and search.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  Thanks! I've separated this into this bigger question with a explanations because it's of a little different nature.

regarding the keywords array: it actually works if I do `collection.find({ "keywordst3": { "$all": keywords}})`  it does match each member of `kewords` with members of `keywordst3` so it does it without the regex.

As about the `$text` - I've written down the challenge there. The scoring is a bit odd. I get a score of 1 for a match of both words and a score of 1 for a match of one word 2-3 times. This makes the scoring a little "fuzzy"...

Comment: It may "work" but understand that your word `"ball"` without the word boundary `\b` will match `"balling"` and `"ballgame"` etc and not just `"ball"`. It **will not work** with if the field contains `"the ball game tomorrow"`, and would **only** work with an array such as `["the","ball","game","tomorrow"]` unless you use regular expressions anyway.

Comment: The "text" search would just match `"ball"` and `"balls"` and ignore the other words. So you probably **do** want the boundaries. As for the rest of the question, it gets a bit "too broad". Like I said, there are other considerations when choosing between the "text" and "regex" matches or even an "array of words" in the document to directly use a list with `$all` rather than regular expressions. Those are a **lot more important** things to consider than what you are focusing on.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  I always have an array of keywords in `keywordst3` field. it's always a list of keywords `["the","ball","game","tomorrow"]`. WHen I use `$all`  i used it against a field with array of keywords. WHen I use `$text` i used it against a text index of course.

And back to the `$text` - i get the concept. i just don't get the scoring rules. If I know what the score of 0.5 means for a phrase `toy ball` and what the score 1... or 2...means for it - that'd make the life much easier. Score 1 could be for all words found and it can also be for 1 word found three times in the text.

Comment: Then it's a no-brainer. Use `$all`. You can exact match and it will "run rings around a text search". The main consideration was the "cost" of creating and maintaing the keywords list. But if you are happy with that and it's just going to be there, then use it. To be clear, the only reason "text search" and "regex" queries were discussed on your previous question, is because you never mentioned the field was already an array of words.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for missing the bit about the keywords array. I maintain in during the population of that collection - so it's always there.